# How should I separate the view of a domain from the domain model itself in java?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

How can I decouple how (or even if) a domain model is viewed from the implementation of the view itself. As an example consider the following code:

```
public class Student
{
    private Set<Course> enrollment;
    public void enroll(Course c){
        // domain implementation
    }
    public void unenroll(Course c) {
       // domain implementation
    }

}
```

This is a pretty simple example, but it's fine for what I'm asking. What would be a good way of ensuring that the view of this object is decoupled from the actual domain functionality? For example this student should be able to be represented in XML, JSON, or even some sort of game, or not have a view of any kind.

Some of the approaches I've thought of could be something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="student")
public class StudentXmlView implements XmlView<Student> {

    @XmlElement(name="enrollment")  
    private XmlVeiw<Set<Course>> enrollmentView;
}
```

Would this sort of approach be suitable, or is there some best practice that is typically used in java for separating domain from it's view?

Comment: CQRS is perfect for this

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes thank you I just [looked it up](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and looks like exactly what I was thinking of.

Comment: yes, with CQRS you can have how many read-models you want, even aggregating more write-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CQRS architecture is perfect for this kind of separation: it separates the write model (the Aggregates in DDD) from the read model.

The write model is specially designed to protect the business invariants regarding state changes. It executes commands. It cannot be queried.

The read model is designed to be fast and fit for a particular use case. Each use case has other read model. Here you can use whatever technology is best suited.

There is no equality between the write and the read models. You could have 3 write models and 1 read model, or any combination.

In a microservice architecture, each model (write or read) can be a microservice.

The next thing after CQRS is Event sourcing.

Comment: One question: If you can have any number of separate models for read and write how do you maintain the model's functionality with intention revealing interfaces? DDD seems to suggest that the core functionality of the domain should be maintained on the domain model, but with multiple versions of a model as CQRS how do you maintain that functional integrity?

Comment: @TaylorHandy you don't have multiple write models of the same concept but only one. The read model is the one that is adapted/split/recombined to better fulfill the purpose of displaying the data to the user faster and cleaner. The write model's design is driven by the domain invariants and consistency requirements. Regarding intention revealing interface: what is more intention revealing than a write model having command methods like `registerUser` generating `UserRegistered` event and `whatIsTheNumberOfRegisteredUsers` method from a `RegisteredUsersCounter` read model?

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot more sense, thank you. So with your example it would be something along the lines of a `UserRepository` registering the user which would push a `UserRegistered` event to some Event publisher which `RegisteredUsersCounter` would see and then update its count. Something like that?

Comment: @TaylorHandy yes